# Using VBA to insert x number of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a spreadsheet that that generates rows on other sheets based upon a cell in the first sheet. After getting it kind of working and finishing all the dynamic formulas I found that the last cell requires a different set of formulas, and now my original VBA script doesn't work. My original script just added the new rows at the end, now it needs to insert the new cells at row 7 shifting that row down and copying row 6 into all the newly generated cells.

Here's my original script..

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
' This routing will copy rows based on the quantity to a new sheet.
Dim rngSinglecell12 As Range
Dim rngQuantityCells12 As Range

Dim rngSinglecell467 As Range
Dim rngQuantityCells467 As Range

Dim rngSinglecell358 As Range
Dim rngQuantityCells358 As Range

' Set this for the range where the Quantity column exists. This works only if there are no empty cells
Set rngQuantityCells12 = Range("G9", Range("G9").End(xlDown))

Set rngQuantityCells467 = Range("D9", Range("D9").End(xlDown))

Set rngQuantityCells358 = Range("F9", Range("F9").End(xlDown))

For Each rngSinglecell12 In rngQuantityCells12

     'Check if this cell actually contains a number and if the number is greater than 0
    If IsNumeric(rngSinglecell12.Value) And rngSinglecell12.Value > 0 Then


        Sheets("Line 1").Rows("6").Copy (Sheets("Line 1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rngSinglecell12.Value + 1))
        Sheets("Line 2").Rows("6").Copy (Sheets("Line 2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rngSinglecell12.Value + 1))

    End If
Next

For Each rngSinglecell467 In rngQuantityCells467

    ' Check if this cell actually contains a number and if the number is greater than 0
    If IsNumeric(rngSinglecell467.Value) And rngSinglecell467.Value > 0 Then

        Sheets("Line 4").Rows("6").Copy (Sheets("Line 4").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rngSinglecell467.Value + 1))
        Sheets("Line 6").Rows("6").Copy (Sheets("Line 6").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rngSinglecell467.Value + 1))
        Sheets("Line 7").Rows("6").Copy (Sheets("Line 7").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rngSinglecell467.Value + 1))

    End If
Next

For Each rngSinglecell358 In rngQuantityCells358

    ' Check if this cell actually contains a number and if the number is greater than 0
    If IsNumeric(rngSinglecell358.Value) And rngSinglecell358.Value > 0 Then

        Sheets("Line 3").Rows("6").Copy (Sheets("Line 3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rngSinglecell358.Value + 1))
        Sheets("Line 5").Rows("6").Copy (Sheets("Line 5").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rngSinglecell358.Value + 1))
        Sheets("Line 8").Rows("6").Copy (Sheets("Line 8").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(rngSinglecell358.Value + 1))

    End If
Next


End Sub
```

I am assuming it will be something like this

```
    Rows("6:6").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Rows("7:7").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

but i"m not sure how to really icorporate that into the script I have or if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself...

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

' This routing will copy rows based on the quantity to a new sheet.
Dim rngSinglecell12 As Range
Dim rngQuantityCells12 As Range

Dim rngSinglecell467 As Range
Dim rngQuantityCells467 As Range

Dim rngSinglecell358 As Range
Dim rngQuantityCells358 As Range

' Set this for the range where the Quantity column exists. This works only if there are no empty cells
Set rngQuantityCells12 = Range("G9", Range("G9").End(xlDown))

Set rngQuantityCells467 = Range("D9", Range("D9").End(xlDown))

Set rngQuantityCells358 = Range("F9", Range("F9").End(xlDown))

For Each rngSinglecell12 In rngQuantityCells12

     'Check if this cell actually contains a number and if the number is greater than 0
    If IsNumeric(rngSinglecell12.Value) And rngSinglecell12.Value > 0 Then

        Sheets("Line 1").Rows("6").Copy
        Sheets("Line 1").Rows("7").Resize(rngSinglecell12.Value).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Sheets("Line 2").Rows("6").Copy
        Sheets("Line 2").Rows("7").Resize(rngSinglecell12.Value).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End If
Next

For Each rngSinglecell467 In rngQuantityCells467

    ' Check if this cell actually contains a number and if the number is greater than 0
    If IsNumeric(rngSinglecell467.Value) And rngSinglecell467.Value > 0 Then

        Sheets("Line 4").Rows("6").Copy
        Sheets("Line 4").Rows("7").Resize(rngSinglecell467.Value - 2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Sheets("Line 6").Rows("6").Copy
        Sheets("Line 6").Rows("7").Resize(rngSinglecell467.Value - 2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Sheets("Line 7").Rows("6").Copy
        Sheets("Line 7").Rows("7").Resize(rngSinglecell467.Value - 2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End If
Next

For Each rngSinglecell358 In rngQuantityCells358

    ' Check if this cell actually contains a number and if the number is greater than 0
    If IsNumeric(rngSinglecell358.Value) And rngSinglecell358.Value > 0 Then

        Sheets("Line 3").Rows("6").Copy
        Sheets("Line 3").Rows("7").Resize(rngSinglecell358.Value - 2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Sheets("Line 5").Rows("6").Copy
        Sheets("Line 5").Rows("7").Resize(rngSinglecell358.Value - 2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Sheets("Line 8").Rows("6").Copy
        Sheets("Line 8").Rows("7").Resize(rngSinglecell358.Value - 2).Insert Shift:=xlDown
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Calculate
End Sub
```